# "Couldn't communicate with a helper application" authenticating

Tags: xcode

I've been trying to authenticate with my Apple Id in Xcode, but it's consistently showing the "Couldn't communicate with a helper application" dialog. I restarted Xcode, computer, etc. It also doesn't seem temporary as it's happening a couple of days already.

[image]

Can reproduce it with all my Xcode installations: 12 beta, 12 and 11.3.1. MacOS 11 beta. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I had to do:

Delete the `Developer` directories:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/
rm -rf /Library/Developer/
```

And re-install Xcode.

This did **not** help:

- Only reinstalling Xcode
- Upgrading/downgrading Xcode
- Upgrading from the OS beta to release version.

Comment: Possibly the the Developer libraries is one potential source of this problem but it's not the only possible source. In general this solution will not always work. I recommend using the CONSOLE APPLICATION to find the source of the problem (an app). For me it was an external app (Dropbox) as identified in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work in my case. CONSOLE logs indicate that the helper application that was being invoked when SAVE was invoked was Dropbox. I removed DROPBOX from my Mac and the problem was eliminated. Easy to say but took me a week of frustration to get to that point. I would recommend using the CONSOLE app on MAC and likely similar app on Windows to find offending app very quickly. I will try reinstalling Dropbox with correct credentials and expect it to be compatible after reinstalling. Most likely was a credentials problem.